# Using the windows api and C++, how could I load an exe from the hard drive and run it in its own thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

For the sake of learning I'm trying to do what the OS does when launching a program ie. parsing a PE file and giving it a thread of execution.

If I have two exe's one called foo.exe and the other bar.exe, how could I have foo.exe load the contents of bar.exe into memory then have it execute from there in its own thread? I know how to get it into memory using MapViewOfFile or by simple loading the contents on the hard drive into a buffer. I'm assuming simply copying the contents of bar.exe on disk into its own suspended thread and running it wouldn't work. I am semi-familiar with PE file internals. All help is very much appreciated, of course :)

Comment: While I could be wrong, I don't think you can just load an executable by hand and expect it to work when you call it... it usually a lot of assumptions about being the main runner of the current process, and I don't think things will work if you try to host it inside another process.

Comment: @Lambert: If not a thread then would a process work? Using CreateProcess.

Comment: @returneax: Huh... why not? Isn't that the right way to do it?

Comment: @Lambert : *"by hand"*.... LOL!

Comment: @Lambert: Well, if it would work in a process why wouldn't it work in a thread? Fundamentally, isn't a process a main thread of execution. If you can supply a thread of execution and guarantee no conflicts with any other threads what is so different between a thread and a process?

Comment: @Lambert : not only the *"right way"*. that is the ONLY way!

Comment: @Nawaz: Er, not actually. You can also use `RtlCreateUserProcess` and other things, it's just very *very* hard.

Comment: @returneax: Well... because, for example, it's hard enough just to simulate what `CreateProcess` itself does, let alone trying to tweak it and doing something that's not meant to be done. (There's also DLL conflicts that can happen and other things, but I'm ignoring the issues right now... all I can say is, "good luck".)

Comment: @Lambert: Yes, this would be quite the undertaking. Although, as you said, it must be inherently possible. Probably not the best way to learn ;) I'll start with just using CreateProcess.

Comment: @Lambert : What I meant is that you've to run it as a process, it cannot run in a thread of some other process.  There may be different APIs to run the executable, however.

Comment: @Nawaz: Could you clarify your last statement to Lambert? I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah. Well, (@returneax) the reason is, you'd need to (1) map the exe image to your memory, (2) perform fixups on the addresses, (3) create a process, (4) set up the process's environment (which will likely cause conflicts), (5) create a thread, (6) set up the thread's stack, (7) load all the DLLs, (8) call the static constructors and do anything needed for thread-local storage, etc. -- features of the PE file format, and (9) give control to the method. I probably forgot half of the other things too. It's just too hard to actually do.

Comment: @returneax : what is there difficult to understand? different APIs means different APIs. You've `CreateProcess()`, you also have `RtlCreateUserProcess()`, `CreateProcessAsUser()`, `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`. All are different, right? But all create `process`. Process means it has its own address space, it doesn't run within other process.

Answer (score 4):

First, Lambert is correct.  EXEs run in their own process. The reason why EXEs can't load into another process is because they are not compiled for relative addressing and can not be easily have its code remapped to another address.  Developers launch other EXE programs with the Win32 system call, "CreateProcess".  But I don't think that was your question...

I think you want to know how to manually load code from a binary into running process (and have it run on a dedicated thread).  Most developers just call LoadLibrary/GetProcessAddress to map a DLL into the process space and CreateThread to launch a thread.

So I think what you are basically asking, "how do I implement the core component of the kernel and OS known as the loader?"  Or put another way, "how do I implement CreateProcess and LoadLibrary myself?"

The OS loader does more than just parse binary files into memory and set the instruction pointer to the first line of code. It also loads other dependent DLLs. Because the process may already have allocated other code to run at the target address that the DLL was compiled to, it may also have to do fixup the addresses of the DLL to load it at another address. I'm likely missing many other steps including virtual memory allocation for the binary code itself.

I do recommend looking at the [Richter book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572315482) for its sections on processes, threads, and DLLs.  He discusses a bit of this and some details on parsing the PE format of DLLs.

Studying the Linux kernel implementation of how it loads .SO files into a process space may also be a worthwhile study.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this would be mostly an issue for load-time DLL's right? If all the DLL's were loaded at runtime in a program a lot of these issues could be avoided. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: [Edit]: I'm basing this off of what I've learned recently: that DLLs that will absolutely be used by a program are stored hard-coded in the Import Address Table.

Comment: @returneax: Even those need to be checked; you cannot assume that the base address they state is available. You load DLLs in memory COW, which is why it's good to load them at their preferred base address: no patching saves you the COW copy.

Answer (score 3):

Executable always runs as a separate *process*. It cannot be made to run in a *thread* of some other *process*. However you can run your executable *as a process* from a thread of some other process. Have a look at [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function!

Comment: Maybe not technically, but here's a very simple example. Imagine a "Hello, world" program. Now what if we extracted the op codes for all of the functionality in said program... mainly printing "Hello, world." If we took the extracted op codes and placed them in their own suspended thread and resumed that thread we would have the same functionality as the "Hello, world." on disk, right?

Comment: @returneax : right. but how would one do that? I don't think Windows APIs can help you extracting opcodes. You need to write your own API to parse executable and extract opcodes. But it would be huge project in itself!

Comment: @returneax: You *do* know that you'd need to re-base the EXE by hand, right? (Not saying it isn't possible, but perhaps not practical.)

Comment: @Lambert: Yes, but that wouldn't be the hardest part, probably.

Comment: The hardest part is trying to get the exact code on ReactOS to even *work* (I've tried it before and failed)... everything else (tweaking it, etc.) can come later...

Comment: @returneax: To name just the first hurdle: those opcodes include the C++ runtime lib. This might reasonably assume it's the first thing to run in the process, and set up the environment. You broke that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Since I personally don't like answers that say "why do you even want to do this?", [here is a link](http://doxygen.reactos.org/dc/de3/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2process_2procsup_8c_afee2bf936652363104809af4473c7a66.html) that would be very helpful. But do be warned that you'll probably not succeed, since EXEs simply don't expect to be run in a thread of another process.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great link. The reason I believe this is mostly possible is because the metadata in a PE file isn't too massive. It seems like most of the issues would be with loading the correct DLL's which might be avoidable by using LoadLibrary etc.